# How to fix Access is denied to path error asp.net application accessing network share

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, directory-structure, windows-server-2012-r2

I have an asp.net app that writes files from the web server to a network share.  The app receives Access to the path '\sanfs1\SupportingDocs\' is denied.

The IIS site has asp.net impersonation and windows authentication enabled. The asp.net auth is set to specific user: ldap_bind that has a password.  the app pool identity is 'Network Service'.  I've tried granting full permissions to IUSR and NETWORK SERVICE on the network share folder but still get access is denied when attempting to upload.

Comment: Besides setting share permissions you need to set file access permissions on the folder itself. This needs to be done on the server that hosts your share (Security tab).

Comment: I did not think about this. I will add permissions there.

Answer (score 1):

> The app receives Access to the path '\sanfs1\SupportingDocs\' is denied.

[IIS - Access to the path is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28360275/iis-access-to-the-path-is-denied?answertab=votes#tab-top)