# How to resolve Access to the folder denied error during file uploading

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am developing a Web Api project with .Net Core. Trying to upload a file using the following code:

```
string path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), UploadFolder);

            using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                registration.File.CopyTo(stream);
            }
```

When the line **using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))** is executing, I am getting following Error:
"Access to the path 'E:\Dynode\AdminApi Web\Admin Api\ApiService\Upload Folder' is denied". I have given full control to "IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool" and "IIS_Users" objects of the Upload folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a name like '`E:\Dynode\AdminApi Web\Admin Api\ApiService\Upload Folder\file.name`'.

Consider `Path.Combine()` to reliably generate the path name.

Or if you are sure your path is ok, change access of your directory like below link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28360298/4588756